# Vector dimensions and variable display

Tags: matlab, random

Hi This is a question about how Matlab displays certain variables, depending on the number of dimensions contained. When I generate `randn(10,2)`, I get a 10X2 table in the workspace window, very easy to copy paste directly from here to excel. However, when I do `randn(10,2,1)`, Matlab creates something that looks like a text file in the workspace. Copying the data over can be a pain when you have `randn(1000,2,1)` for example. Why does Matlab do this?

For context - I want to "pre-generate" (if there's such a word) a set of random numbers for multiple assets and for multiple simulations; hence I'm using `randn(NumSteps,NumAssets,NumSimulations)`. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this...so suggestions are always appreciated.

Comment: Why copy and paste when you can export it right into your Excel file? [`xlswrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html)

Comment: `randn(10,2,1)` is exactly the same as `randn(10,2)`, MATLAB removes the trailing singleton dimensions. Maybe you mean `randn(10,1,2)`?

Comment: Fair point, I was just curious why it's doing that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my viewpoint, `xlswrite` could fix your problems.

Try this:

```
clc; clear;
%%Generate Data
NumSteps=10; NumAssets=10; NumSimulations=5;
RandData=randn(NumSteps,NumAssets,NumSimulations);

%%Output Data into a Excel File
for i=1:NumSimulations
xlswrite('Data.xls',RandData(:,:,i),['Sheet',num2str(i)])
end;
```

Change the value of variables, we could have `NumSimulation` matrixs with `NumSteps x NumAssets` in `sheet1` to `SheetN`.